# SublimeLinter-javac not recognising other packages

Tags: java, sublimetext, javac, sublimelinter

I have a Spring Product That I'm trying the use sublimLinter-javac with, and there are a few packages scattered around the project. The problem is that sublimeLinter-javac is not recognising these packages or the classes within. So I end up with 200+ errors per file making the listing pointless. How do I tell sublimeLinter where to look for these classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing your classpath is not pointing to the right place.
You can find [here](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2) an explanation on how to set project settings.

Finally, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) gives you a sample example on how classpath works