# How can I add Gradle managed dependencies to my classpath using SublimeLinter-javac?

Tags: java, gradle, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm trying to set up linting for my Java project. I'm using Sublime Text 3 to code and using Gradle to build from the command line. My problem is I cannot find a way to add dependencies from Gradle to the classpath so that SublimeLinter3 recognizes them. I've tried adding the cache located at ~/.gradle/cache but that didn't seem to work. Is this actually possible or am I trying to do something which can't be done?

Comment: what about this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843983/sublimelinter-javac-not-recognising-other-packages

Comment: Thanks for replying! I had previously looked at that post and thought that I had tried everything. The problem is that the folders which contain the external libraries are really long. I was able to get one of the dependencies working but the classpath was `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.8.8/bf88c7b27e95cbadce4e7c316a56c3efffda8026/jackson-databind-2.8.8.jar`. I was looking into wildcards so I could include everything in that modules folder but i'm not sure SublimeLinter supports that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to create 2 separate Gradle tasks: One which gathered my dependencies into one folder and another which built my test jar. This way I could add the folder which had the external dependencies to the classpath and the folder which had my build and test jars (for internal dependency resolutions). Here are the Gradle tasks:

```
`task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.testRuntime.files
    into "$buildDir/lib"
}
task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    classifier = 'tests'
    from sourceSets.test.output
}`
```

After I executed these tasks I was able to add the jars which were created by putting this in my sublime-project file:

```
"SublimeLinter": {
    "linters": {
        "javac": {
            "lint": "all",
            "args": [
                "-sourcepath", "/home/griff/orch_engine/src/",
                "-cp", "/home/griff/project/build/lib/*:/home/griff/project/build/libs/*"
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `SublimeLinter-javac` underlying use javac to do the linting [README ref](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-javac/blob/master/README.md#passing-options-to-javac) and [linter.py](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-javac/blob/master/linter.py#L54-L55), you can just config the `-cp` arg to include the classpath directory (`"/gradle/cache/path/*"`).

NOTE, you need to use Java 6 or later to be able to use wildcard option for classpath.

```
"javac": {
    "lint": "all",
    "args": [
        "-encoding", "UTF8",
         "-cp", "/gradle/cache/path/*",
        "-sourcepath", "${project}/src/"
    ]
}
```

Let me know if this works.

[UPDATE]

In "Understanding class path wildcards" section of [Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html), it detailed as follows (which means the nested folders wont handled):

> Subdirectories are not searched recursively. For example, foo/* looks
>   for JAR files only in foo, not in foo/bar, foo/baz, etc.

Comment: That did not work. I tried doing that but all of the external jars are in nested folders (/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.11.164/v132459u2gm2vu2iwb56/aws-java-sdk-s3-sources.jar). I ended up creating 2 gradle tasks. I'll post my solution below.

Comment: any error message? I think the wildcard can take care of the nested folders.

Comment: There were no error messages since all I was doing was putting the above classpath in and checking to see if the changes were highlighted or not. I actually am not sure that the wildcard takes care of nested folders. Is there some other parameter needed for that to happen?

Comment: too sad you can not use `**`

Comment: You can see my answer below :) I was able to use the -d argument to have all of the class files put in a folder which is ignored by git as well!